# Class instance attributes derived from other instance attributes

Tags: python, class, decorator

I apologise if the title is cryptic, I could not think of a way to describe my problem in a sentence. I am building some code in python2.7 that I describe below.

## Minimal working example

My code has a `Parameter` class that implements attributes such as `name` and `value`, which looks something like this.

```
class Parameter(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value=None, error=None, dist=None, prior=None):
        self.name   = name
        self._value = value # given value for parameter, this is going to be changed very often in an MCMC sampler
        self.error  = error # initial estimate of error for the parameter, will only be set once
        self._dist  = dist # a distribution for the parameter, will only be set once
        self.prior  = prior

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @property
    def dist(self):
        return self._dist
```

The class also has several properties that returns the mean, median, etc. of `Parameter.dist` if a distribution is given.

I have another class, e.g. `ParameterSample`, that creates a population of different `Parameter` objects. Some of these `Parameter` objects have their attributes (e.g. `value`, `error`) set using the `Parameter.set_parameter()` function, but some other `Parameter` objects are not explicitly set, but their `value` and `dist` attributes *depend* on some of the other `Parameter` objects that are set:

```
class ParameterSample(object):
    def __init__(self):
        varied_parameters  = ('a', 'b') # parameter names whose `value` attribute is varied
        derived_parameters = ('c',) # parameter names whose `value` attribute is varied, but depends on `a.value` and `b.value`
        parameter_names    = varied_parameters + derived_parameters
        
        # create `Parameter` objects for each parameter name
        for name in parameter_names:
            setattr(self, name, Parameter(name))

    def set_parameter(self, name, **kwargs):
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            if key == 'value':
                key = '_'.join(['', key]) # add underscore to set `Parameter._value`
            setattr(getattr(self, name), key, val) # basically does e.g. `self.a.value = 1`
```

I can now create a `ParameterSample` and use them like this:

```
parobj = ParameterSample()
parobj.set_parameter('a', value=1, error=0.1)
parobj.set_parameter('b', value=2, error=0.5)

parobj.a.value
>>> 1
parobj.b.error
>>> 0.5

parobj.set_parameter('b', value=3)
parobj.b.value
>>> 3
parobj.b.error
>>> 0.5
```

## What I want

What I ultimately want, is to use `Parameter.c` the same way. For example:

```
parobj.c.value
>>> 4 # returns parobj.a.value + parobj.b.value
parobj.c.dist
>>> None # returns a.dist + b.dist, but since they are not currently set it is None
```

`c` therefore needs to be a `Parameter` object with all the same attributes as `a` and `b`, but where its `value` and `dist` are updated according to the current attributes of `a` and `b`.

However, I should also mention that I want to be able to set the allowed prior ranges for parameter `c`, e.g. `parobj.set_parameter('c', prior=(0,10))` before making any calls to its value -- so `c` needs to be an already defined `Parameter` object upon the creation of the `ParameterSample` object.

How would I implement this into my `ParameterSample` class?

## What I've tried

I have tried looking into making my own decorators, but I am not sure if that is the way to go since I don't fully understand how I would use those.

I've also considered adding a @property to `c` that creates a new `Parameter` object every time it is called, but I feel like that is not the way to go since it may slow down the code.

I should also note that the `ParameterSample` class above is going to be inherited in a different class, so whatever the solution is it should be able to be used in this setting:

```
class Companion(ParameterSample)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        super(Companion, self).__init__()

comp = Companion(name='Earth')
comp.set_parameter('a', value=1)
comp.set_parameter('b', value=3)
comp.c.value
>>> 4
```

Comment: Just for the record. You should really switch to python 3 as very soon python 2 will not be supported.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse agreed, but I'll have to do that later as I currently don't have the capacity to port my code over to python 3 at the moment.

Comment: How does `c` know to reference `a` and `b`? What is there is a `d`?

Comment: What if there is a `d`?*

Comment: If I understand your question right, `c` is a an attribute of `ParameterSample` the same way as `a` and `b`, so any of its attributes can be accessed within `ParameterSample` as `self.a.value` etc.

Comment: If there is a `d`, it would be defined as a parameter name in `parameter_names` in `ParameterSample.__init__()`, and an instance would be created, which would be referred to as `self.d`

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work in Python 2 - the `setattr` calls never seemed to propagate the attributes to the child classes (`Companion` would have no `c` attribute).

I was more successful with Python 3 though. Since you have two parameter types (varied vs. derived), it makes sense IMO to have two classes to implement the behavior, instead of treating them all as one.

I added a `DerivedParameter` class, inheriting from `Parameter` that takes a `dependents` argument (along with its parent class' args/kwargs), but redefining `value` and `dist` to give dependent behavior:

```
class DerivedParameter(Parameter):
    def __init__(self, name, dependents, **kwargs):
        self._dependents = dependents
        super().__init__(name, **kwargs)

    @property
    def value(self):
        try:
            return sum(x._value for x in self._dependents if x is not None)
        except TypeError:
            return None

    @property
    def dist(self):
        try:
            return sum(x._dist for x in self._dependents if x is not None)
        except TypeError:
            return None
```

Then I adjusted how your parameter objects are added:

```
class ParameterSample:
    def __init__(self):
        # Store as instance attributes to reference later
        self.varied_params  = ('a', 'b') # parameter names whose `value` attribute is varied
        self.derived_params = ('c',) # parameter names whose `value` attribute is varied, but depends on `a.value` and `b.value`
        # No more combined names

        # create `Parameter` objects for each varied parameter name
        for name in self.varied_params:
            setattr(self, name, Parameter(name))

        # Create `DerivedParameter` objects for each derived parameter
        # Derived parameters depend on all `Parameter` objects. It wasn't
        # clear if this was the desired behavior though.
        params = [v for _, v in self.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, Parameter)]
        for name in self.derived_params:
            setattr(self, name, DerivedParameter(name, params))

    def set_parameter(self, name, **kwargs):
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            if key == 'value':
                key = '_'.join(['', key]) # add underscore to set `Parameter._value`
            setattr(getattr(self, name), key, val) # basically does e.g. `self.a.value = 1`
```

From this, I could then replicate your given example desired behavior:

```
>>> comp = Companion(name='Earth')
>>> comp.set_parameter('a', value=1)
>>> comp.set_parameter('b', value=3)
>>> print(comp.c.value)
>>> print(comp.c.dist)
4
None
>>> comp.set_parameter('c', prior=(0,10))
>>> print(comp.c.prior)
(0, 10)
```

As I pointed out in the comments, the design above ends up causing all derived parameters to use **all** varied parameters as their dependents - effectively making `c` and a potential `d` identical. You should be able to fix this fairly easily with some parameters/conditions.

Overall, I would have to agree with @Error - Syntactical Remorse though. This is a pretty complicated way to go about designing classes and would make maintenance confusing at best. I would strongly encourage you to reconsider your design and try to find an adaptable general solution that doesn't involve dynamic creation of attributes like this.